# How do I see java thread names in Process Explorer?

Tags: windows, java, threads, process-explorer

I have named a thread in my program as "Input Acceptor".

```
userInputThread = new Thread("Input acceptor") {
    public void run(){
        while(true)
           //dosomething
    }
};
```

If I run the program and check Process Explorer, I do not know where to look for it.
I went to java.exe -> Threads tab, but I don't know where to find the thread called "Input acceptor" that I just ran.

Where is this thread? Am I looking in the right process for it?

I just want to debug my program by looking at its running threads. How should I do this in Process Explorer? Or is ProcessExplorer unable to show the name of it? If so, is there any other tool i can use to look at running java threads along with their assigned thread names?

Comment: Thread names are purely a Java thing. I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve here too. How threads work under the hood is implementation-dependent. In the Hotspot JVM they probably correspond to OS threads directly, but I don't think there's anything preventing a hypothetical JVM from implementing light threads managed by the JVM itself, rather than outsourced to OS. Why not use a proper debugger to look at the threads? I think IntelliJ IDEA's debugger can do that.

Comment: The simple answer: you can't. Instead use a Java based tool like "Java Mission Control" or "VisualVM". Additionally development IDEs like Eclipse show the threads when running a program in debug mode.

Comment: I believe you can do this eclipse. If I remember correctly, it can show running threads with their thread names. I will try that. Thanks for the clarification

Answer (score 0):

Setting of system thread names was added in Java <strike>18</strike> 17: [JDK-8238649](https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8238649)

Unfortunately Process Explorer currently does show thread names, I created a [feature request for it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1341178/feature-request-show-thread-name-in-process-explor?comment=question#newest-question-comment). You can upvote it.